# Converting Window coordinates to Axis coordinates in OpenGL

Tags: c++, opengl, window, coordinates

Im creating a simple program in OpenGL to draw rectangles with the mouse. My goal is to click somewhere, drag the mouse and create a rectangle just like you do in paint or any other design program.

I have a view defined like:

```
glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
glOrtho(AXIS_X_MIN, AXIS_X_MAX, AXIS_Y_MIN, AXIS_Y_MAX, AXIS_Z_MIN, AXIS_Z_MAX);
```

and a window defined this way:

```
glutInitWindowSize(WINDOW_WIDTH, WINDOW_HEIGHT);
```

How can I convert the window coordinates which go from 0 to WINDOW_WIDTH and from 0 to WINDOW_HEIGHT into axis coordinates and respective quadrants?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try:

```
double x = x_mouse / (double) WINDOW_WIDTH 
           * (AXIS_X_MAX - AXIS_X_MIN) + AXIS_X_MIN;
double y = (1 - y_mouse / (double) WINDOW_HEIGHT)
           * (AXIS_Y_MAX - AXIS_Y_MIN) + AXIS_Y_MIN;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to make the calculations by "hand", you can always check this small article, that makes use of a function from GLU library that shall do this internally.

http://steinsoft.net/index.php?site=Programming/Code%20Snippets/OpenGL/no8

Answer (score 0):

gluUnProject — transforms map window coordinates to object coordinates.
To be honest, I barely have any idea of how it works. You can check it out here: [OpenGL - gluUnProject](https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man2/xhtml/gluUnProject.xml)

Also if you try this it should work:

```
float coorX = mouseX * width / WINDOW_WIDTH + AXIS_X_MIN;  
float coorY = mouseY * heigth/ WINDOW_HEIGHT + AXIS_Y_MIN;
```

Comment: Your alternative version works with glOrtho() but will not work with a perspective transform (whereas gluUnproject() will work on both cases)